# Tic Tac Toe AI recursing infinitely and not following rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, minimax

I'm not that new to programming, but I haven't tried making too many things without following a tutorial before. This is my first attempt at a REAL project without following a video or copy-pasting code. I created a simple tic tac toe game, it works fine if both players manually choose positions, but when I tried to implement a simple AI using the minimax algorithm, it will play all of the AI moves at once and I have no idea why.

I reviewed the code so many times but I can't figure out why the AI can keep placing pieces/making moves when the player can only make 1 move. According to the code, only 1 move at a time should be allowed. What is going on? When it gets to the AI's turn, the AI places pieces until it wins, no regard for turn or anything. Player pieces are placed too, which is strange because Player needs to be prompted for selection input. I think the problem lies in the minimax function itself, but I can't pinpoint where. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much. Full file:

```
import random
from time import sleep
from math import inf

PLAYER = 0
AI = 1
BOARD = [[' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ']]
#AVAILABLE = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
AVAILABLE = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
SELECTION = 0
TURN = random.randint(0, 1)

def display_board(board):
    print(f'\t[{board[0][0]}] [{board[0][1]}] [{board[0][2]}]\n\t[{board[1][0]}] [{board[1][1]}] [{board[1][2]}]\n\t[{board[2][0]}] [{board[2][1]}] [{board[2][2]}]')

def convert_position(available_locations, position):
    if position in available_locations:
        available_locations.remove(position)
    position -= 1
    converted = (position // 3, position % 3)
    return converted

def is_valid_location(board):
    pass

def place_piece(board, position, player):
    a, b = position
    if a in [0, 1, 2] and b in [0, 1, 2]:
        if board[a][b] == ' ' and player == PLAYER:
            board[a][b] = 'X'
        if board[a][b] == ' ' and player == AI:
            board[a][b] = 'O'

def clear_board(board):
    board = [[' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ']]
    return board

def is_win_player(board):
    if board[0][0] != ' ' and board[0][1] == board[0][0] and board[0][2] == board[0][0]:
        if board[0][0] == 'X':
            return True
    if board[1][0] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[1][0] and board[1][2] == board[1][0]:
        if board[1][0] == 'X':
            return True
    if board[2][0] != ' ' and board[2][1] == board[2][0] and board[2][2] == board[2][0]:
        if board[2][0] == 'X':
            return True
    if board[0][0] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[0][0] and board[2][2] == board[0][0]:
        if board[0][0] == 'X':
            return True
    if board[2][0] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[2][0] and board[0][2] == board[2][0]:
        if board[2][0] == 'X':
            return True
    if board[0][0] != ' ' and board[1][0] == board[0][0] and board[2][0] == board[0][0]:
        if board[0][0] == 'X':
            return True
    if board[0][1] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[0][1] and board[2][1] == board[0][1]:
        if board[0][1] == 'X':
            return True
    if board[0][2] != ' ' and board[1][2] == board[0][2] and board[2][2] == board[0][2]:
        if board[0][2] == 'X':
            return True

def is_win_ai(board):
    if board[0][0] != ' ' and board[0][1] == board[0][0] and board[0][2] == board[0][0]:
        if board[0][0] == 'O':
            return True
    if board[1][0] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[1][0] and board[1][2] == board[1][0]:
        if board[1][0] == 'O':
            return True
    if board[2][0] != ' ' and board[2][1] == board[2][0] and board[2][2] == board[2][0]:
        if board[2][0] == 'O':
            return True
    if board[0][0] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[0][0] and board[2][2] == board[0][0]:
        if board[0][0] == 'O':
            return True
    if board[2][0] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[2][0] and board[0][2] == board[2][0]:
        if board[2][0] == 'O':
            return True
    if board[0][0] != ' ' and board[1][0] == board[0][0] and board[2][0] == board[0][0]:
        if board[0][0] == 'O':
            return True
    if board[0][1] != ' ' and board[1][1] == board[0][1] and board[2][1] == board[0][1]:
        if board[0][1] == 'O':
            return True
    if board[0][2] != ' ' and board[1][2] == board[0][2] and board[2][2] == board[0][2]:
        if board[0][2] == 'O':
            return True

def score_eval(board):
    for row in range(0, 3):
        if board[row][0] == board[row][1] and board[row][1] == board[row][2]:
            if board[row][0] == 'O':
                return 10
            if board[row][0] == 'X':
                return -10
    for col in range(0, 3):
        if board[0][col] == board[1][col] and board[1][col] == board[2][col]:
            if board[row][0] == 'O':
                return 10
            if board[row][0] == 'X':
                return -10

    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        if board[0][0] == 'O':
            return 10
        if board[0][0] == 'X':
            return -10
    if board[2][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[0][2]:
        if board[2][0] == 'O':
            return 10
        if board[2][0] == 'X':
            return -10

def is_tie(board):
    counter = 0
    for array in board:
        for index in array:
            if index == ' ':
                counter += 1
    if counter == 0:
        return True

def is_terminal(board):
    return is_tie(board) or is_win_player(board) or is_win_ai(board)

def minimax(board, depth, maximizingPlayer, available_positions):
    valid_locations = available_positions
    print(valid_locations)
    terminal = is_terminal(board)
    if depth == 0 or terminal:
        if terminal:
            if is_win_ai(board):
                return None, 99999999
            if is_win_player(board):
                return None, -99999999
            if is_tie(board): 
                return None, 1
        else:
            return None, score_eval(board)
    if maximizingPlayer:
        value = -inf
        selection = random.choice(valid_locations)
        for num in valid_locations:
            board_copy = board.copy()
            position = convert_position(valid_locations, num)
            place_piece(board_copy, position, AI)
            new_score = minimax(board_copy, depth-1, False, valid_locations)[1]
            if new_score > value:
                value = new_score
                selection = num
        return selection, value
    else:
        value = inf
        selection = random.choice(valid_locations)
        for num in valid_locations:
            board_copy = board.copy()
            position = convert_position(valid_locations, num)
            place_piece(board_copy, position, PLAYER)
            new_score = minimax(board_copy, depth-1, True, valid_locations)[1]
            if new_score < value:
                value = new_score
                selection = num
        return selection, value



while SELECTION != 'QUIT':
    print('\t< Tic Tac Toe >\n')
    print('\tPlease make a selection:')
    print("\t'PLAY' to play a game")
    print("\t'QUIT' to exit application\n")
    SELECTION = input('> ').upper()
    if SELECTION != 'QUIT' and SELECTION != 'PLAY':
        print(SELECTION)
        print('Please enter a valid selection.')
    elif SELECTION == 'PLAY':
        game_over = False
        while not game_over:
            display_board(BOARD)
            if is_tie(BOARD):
                print('Tie game. No winner.')
                input('Press any key to continue...')
                game_over = True
            elif TURN == PLAYER:
                print("Player's turn!")
                position = int(input('Please enter a number 1 - 9 to make a mark: '))
                selection = convert_position(AVAILABLE, position)
                place_piece(BOARD, selection, PLAYER)
                if is_win_player(BOARD):
                    print('Player has won the game!')
                    display_board(BOARD)
                    game_over = True
            elif TURN == AI:
                print("AI's turn!")
                sleep(0.9)
                x, y = minimax(BOARD, 7, True, AVAILABLE)  #x = position, y = score
                selection = convert_position(AVAILABLE, x)
                place_piece(BOARD, selection, AI)
                if is_win_ai(BOARD):
                    print('AI has won the game!')
                    display_board(BOARD)
                    game_over = True
            TURN += 1
            TURN = TURN % 2
            print(AVAILABLE)
        BOARD = clear_board(BOARD)
        AVAILABLE = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: If you're going to work on a REAL project, I strongly suggest that you first read and start following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make your code easier to read and follow — both for yourself and for others.

Comment: If I run the game and select `5` as my first number to make a mark, a `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'` occurs — because apparently that's what `score_eval()` returned after being called 8 times. This indicates there is a code path in it that falls off the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible culprits is the bit which attempts to "clone" the board in your minimax function:

```
board_copy = board.copy()
```

In Python, `list.copy` method returns a *shallow copy* of a list, which is essentially a new list with 3 elements which are references to the "rows" in your original board. Try using `copy.deepcopy()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

```
import copy
...
board_copy = copy.deepcopy(board)
```